# Como fazer um relogio / como fazer rodar em background?

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um codigo que roda um relogio para que mostre quando expirar o tempo de  uso de uma maquina(informado pelo usuario).
No codigo o relogio fica dentro de um while(1), dessa forma nao tem como o usuario informar o tempo de uso da maquina.

o codigo do relogio é esse:

```
        while (1 == 1) {
        Sleep (100);
        segundos++;
        system("cls");

        if (segundos > 59) { minutos++; segundos = 0; }
        if (minutos > 59) { horas++; minutos = 0; }
        if (horas > 23) { dias++; horas = 0; }
        if (mes > 30) { mes++; dias = 0; }

        printf("%d: %d: %d %d %d", mes, dias, horas, minutos, segundos);

}
```

E o codigo para que seja informado o tempo é esse:

```
printf("Digite 1 para maquinas, 2 para pessoas, 3 para estoque, 4 para horarios, 5 para alterar o nome do laboratorio e 6 para finalizar.\n");

scanf("%d", &y);
system("cls");

if(y == 1){
    printf("Vamo comecar o cadastro das maquinas.\n");
    printf("Quantas maquinas deseja cadastrar?\n");
        scanf("%d", &z);
    for(i=0; i<z; i++){
        fflush(stdin);
    printf("Qual o nome da maquina %d?\n", i+1);
        gets(m[c].maquina);

    printf("Qual o tempo de vida util da maquina?\n");
    printf("Expresse o tempo em meses.\n");
        scanf("%d", &m[c].tempo);
        fflush(stdin);
        c++;

    }

    system("cls");

    printf("Muito bem, o cadastramento das maquinas foi um sucesso!\n");
    printf("O programa avisa automaticamente quando o tempo de vida util da maquina expirar.\n");
}
    printf("Informacoes do cadastro de maquinas:\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<c; i++){
        printf("CADASTRO DA MAQUINA %d\n", i+1);
        printf("O nome da maquina eh %s\n", m[i].maquina);
        printf("A vida util da maquina eh de %d meses\n", m[i].tempo);
        if(m[i].maquina == mes){
            printf("A maquina necessita de manuntençao.\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
```

Gostaria de saber se tem outra forma de criar um relogio ou se tem como fazer esse relogio rodar no background do codigo.

Answer (score 1):

voce pode usar a a função time para pegar o tempo do sistema, no caso o sleep da uma parada no processador seria como executar um loop que nao faz nada apenas para delay ou para gastar ciclos de maquina, por outro lado pelo time voce pega o tempo atual do sistema e não precisa ficar esperando nada, veja um exemplo basico do seu funcionamento

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
   time_t tempo;
   struct tm *tempo_formatado;

   //pega o tempo atual em segundos deis de 1970
   tempo = time(NULL);

   //colocamos o tempo na estrutura tm para
   //converter em segundos, min, horas, dias e etc
   tempo_formatado = localtime(&tempo);

   //exibimos pela estrutra
   printf("segundos %d \n",tempo_formatado->tm_sec);
   printf("minutos %d \n",tempo_formatado->tm_min);
   printf("horas %d \n",tempo_formatado->tm_hour); 
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no caso do relogio e bem simples basta pegar o tempo atual em um loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
   time_t tempo;
   struct tm *tempo_formatado;

   while(1){    
      tempo = time(NULL);

      tempo_formatado = localtime(&tempo);

      printf("%d",tempo_formatado->tm_hour);
      printf(":%d",tempo_formatado->tm_min);
      printf(":%d\n",tempo_formatado->tm_sec);  
   }
}
```

outra coisa que é possivel é um contador bastando ver a diferença do tempo entre dois time

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
   time_t tempo, tempo2;
   tempo = time(NULL);
   sleep(2);
   tempo2 = time(NULL);
   printf("%d \n", tempo2 - tempo);
}
```

ou ate mesmo comparar um time para ver se passou de um determinado tempo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
   time_t tempo, tempo2;
   tempo = time(NULL);
   sleep(7);
   tempo2 = time(NULL);
   if(tempo2 > tempo + 5){
       printf("mais de 5 segundo\n");
   }
}
```

bom tem muitas coisas que da para fazer usando o time ^^

Comment: O problema do `time()` é que o AP quer um método que _"... não [tenha] como o usuário informar o tempo de uso da máquina"_, e o usuário pode atrasar indefinidamente a manutenção alterando o relógio do Windows se você usar `time()`.

Comment: Tenho uma duvida, pelo que entendi o time só pega o horário do sistema, tem como pegar a data do sistema ? Já que no caso do meu programa se passariam anos, meses e não apenas horas.

Comment: Seria necessário poder manipular essa data também, comparando com inteiros, ou seja, teria de ser informada em inteiros.

Comment: wrmute nesse caso ai seria uma boa pegar a hora de de um servidor externo por socket, ruim seria se pessoa puxar o cabo da net ai programa nao funciona kkk, usar a api GetTickCount seria uma alternativa tambem.

Comment: Gabriel o time pega o dia, semana, mes e ano tambem. para o dia no mes voce usa o tm_mday, o dia no ano tm_yday, o mes use tm_mon (começa no 0), o ano use tm_year (ira retornar 117 = 2017)

Comment: @kodonokami: `time()` retorna `time_t`, que é o número de segundos decorridos desde 1º de janeiro de 1970, GMT. para retornar uma `struct tm` (com `tm_yday` etc) tem que dizer `localtime(time(NULL))` ou `gmtime(time(NULL))` para fazer a conversão (o primeiro é no fuso horário local, o segundo em UTC).